# Is it true that $(A\times A)-(B\times B) = (A - B)\times (A -B)$ for any two sets A,B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't know how to prove set inclusions with Cartesian products, can someone explain how?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5):

This is not true: let $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1\}$. Then $(A×A)\setminus (B×B)=\{(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ but $(A\setminus B)×(A\setminus B)=\{(2,2)\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see. Suppose $A$ is a finite set with $a$ elements, $B$ is a finite set with $b$ elements, and $B$ is a subset of $A$. Then $(A\times A)\setminus(B\times B)$ has $a^2-b^2$ elements, while $(A\setminus B)\times(A\setminus B)$ has $(a-b)^2$ elements. Is $a^2-b^2=(a-b)^2$?